# Giving access to third party application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am a developer working on an application that will access O365 data via the Graph API. I have registered an application under my company account. I have authentication working on a per-user basis. Now I am trying to get it to work so that a tenant administrator can grant permission to my application for data access on an organization-wide basis.  I have this working as well - I used the /adminconsent endpoint to bring the administrator to a page where he granted the consent.

What I am wondering about is the line in the documentation that says "You can rely on an administrator to grant the permissions your app needs at the Azure portal". I am trying to figure out what that procedure is so I can document it for admin users.  I thought perhaps it was to go to App Registrations - there I see an option to create a new registration. But this has it's own Client Id.  Don't I somehow have to give it the Client Id of my own application? Or is the idea that the tenant admin will supply the Client Id of his app to my app?  Or am I in the wrong area altogether?

BTW in case it is relevant, I am not using any authentication library, just making direct http calls from a C++ program running on the Windows desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, your application is an multi-tenant application. Only you or the administrators in your tenant can grant the permissions to your application. The administrators from other tenants can grant consent to use your application, but they can not control the permissions.

**Update:**

You can grant admin consent by calling admin consent endpoint.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/adminconsent?
  client_id={your_tenant_client_id}
  &state=12345
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
    &scope=
    https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

If you want to [grant admin consent via Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#grant-admin-consent-from-the-azure-portal). The application must already been provisioned in your tenant. For example, an app could be provisioned in your tenant if at least one user has already consented to the application.

Comment: This is exactly correct. If the static permissions required by your app change, admins can go through the admin consent flow again to accept those. Alternatively you can use dynamic consent to require new scopes when they are needed.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  But I still don't have the foggiest notion of how the tenant admin would grant access to my app using the Azure portal.  Can someone point me in the direction of a step by step procedure?

Comment: Thanks - going through the per-user authentication is the secret I was looking for.  Now my application shows up in Azure under Enterprise Applications.  I now have a "consent" button to push.  This seems to be identical to just going to the adminconsent endpoint, so I'm not sure if there is any advantage to using the portal. But I think I'm good to go now.